# Server side customvalidator (asp + vb.net) not firing

Tags: .net, vb.net, validation, customvalidator

I know this has been asked a lot, but I have a server-side custom validator that is not being fired, and I cannot find why (also, I've copied examples that work from other places and cannot make it work...)

The code:

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="MyValidator" runat="server" ErrorMessage="My error message" OnServerValidate="MyValidator_OnServerValidate" />
```

Validate function

```
    Protected Sub MyValidator_OnServerValidate(ByVal source As Object, ByVal args As System.Web.UI.WebControls.ServerValidateEventArgs) Handles MyValidator.ServerValidate
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 0
    args.IsValid = False
End Sub
```

This is the last test I'm doing (copied from other question), but I've also tried attaching the validator to one control (and adding the ValidateEmptyText) and removing the `handles MyValidator.ServerValidate` and adding it to the tag with `onServerValidate`.

(I'm usually a Java programmer, so it can be a very basic error I should have seen, don't underestimate my .Net ignorance)

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**: Add the code for the submit button...

```
<asp:Button ID="lbGuardar" runat="server" CssClass="button" Text="Guardar" CausesValidation="true" ></asp:Button>
```

**EDIT 2:** Added a `Page.validate()` on my button code, and it does not call the server side of the validator. Also, the custom validator is being called (at least the client/javascript side of it, but not the server side)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did not manage to make it work. Removed custom validator, and made validations inside the logic.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Off the top of my head, I would try changing Protected Sub to Public Sub.</strike>

***EDIT:** I just tested your code and what you have works for me. I went into Debug and clicked a button that posted back where it went into MyValidator.ServerValidate first, as it should. It turns the page invalid and shows the Error Message.*

Comment: Might be some additional config I am missing? Is it possible that visual studio is not changing some underlying file?

Comment: Not sure.  What does your page declaration look like? My test I ran has `<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeBehind="TestPage.aspx.vb" Inherits="TestApp.TestPage" %>`

Comment: `<%@ Control Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="ucAltaCliente.ascx.vb" Inherits="SGI08.ucAltaCliente" %>`
but i've changed the `AutoEventWireup` to true and it did not work either...
If it helps, other requiredvalidators on the application do work...

Comment: Try another page. Just create a test page and use that same code. Sometimes I've found that if create a new page and copy/paste the old into the new it fixes weird errors like that.

Comment: Did not work... I've also removed all references to validators, added some requiredfieldvalidator and they worked, but when I added customvalidators they don't work...

Answer (score 1):

Should be a public method and doesn't need the handles.

```
Public Sub MyValidator_OnServerValidate(ByVal source As Object, ByVal args As System.Web.UI.WebControls.ServerValidateEventArgs)

    Dim i As Integer
    i = 0
    args.IsValid = False

End Sub
```

Comment: In what way doesn't it work. If you put a breakpoint on the method does that trigger, or does it not even reach that?

Comment: It does not reach the breakpoints inside the `onServerValidate`. It's weird, because if I add a ClientSide validation, it is being called, but the server validation is not being called, not even if I programatically force a Page.validate()...
[I allways debug with breakpoint on the method, and it never reaches...]

Comment: Hmm. Have you tried creating a new server control with another custom validator to see if that one fires? Personally I'd try creating a new project from scratch and doing the same to see if that works and then compare the differences.

Comment: The new project worked... did not find any interesting difference, will keep on searching